# 2-dimensional inelastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

I am currently struggling with a problem which I thought seems pretty easy but I am unsure how to even start :D Maybe you could help me.

> Two identical balls with the same mass, both with an initial velocity of "v" collide with each other inelastically, so that both their velocities are 1/3v, and they are móving away from each other (not glued together). How big was the angle between their intial paths before the collision? I've done a rough sketch:

[image]

I know I need to separate the $x$- and $y$-components of the momentum vectors, but how do I do that, with the little information given?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, given both balls are identical, if you select the x-axis such that $\theta_1 = \theta_2$, then $\theta_1' = \theta_2'$.

The initial momentum in the x-direction is then given by, $2mv\cos\theta_1$.

Similarly the final momentum in the x-direction is then given by $\frac{2}{3}mv\cos\theta_1'$.

Clearly these can only be equal when $\cos\theta_1 = \cos\theta_1' = 0$, and therefore the angle between the directions of velocities is 180 degrees, or $\pi$ radians.